# Wrap all individual words in a span tag based on their first letter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to wrap each individual word on a webpage in a  tag so I can style them individually based on their starting letter.

I have found this method of wrapping each word in a span tag individually, but I can't figure out how to vary the class based on the first letter of the word.

```
let e = document.getElementById('words');

e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/(^|<\/?[^>]+>|\s+)([^\s<]+)/g, '$1<span class="word">$2</span>');
```

Comment: Your implementation does not work well in nested html tags. e.g. <span><sup id='bulabula'></sup><span>. For a more robust revision, try the following: e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>|[^<>\s]+/g, function(match) { return match.startsWith('<') ? match : '<span class="word">' + match + '</span>'; });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve can't be done with regex if you want to reference the individual words.

I've wrote a little snippet that uses `document.querySelector()` instead

outerText property on the query selector object returns a plain text string which is later converted to an array with `split()` function

Then it simply loops over the array and appends the style tag and to get the first letter I've used `substring()` function

```js
const words = document.querySelector("#words").outerText.split(" ");
const wordsDiv = document.querySelector("#words")

wordsDiv.innerHTML = ""
words.map((el) => {
  wordsDiv.innerHTML += `<span class="${el.substring(0, 1)}">${el}</span> `
})
```

```html
<div id="words">red green blue orange</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let e = document.getElementById('words');
// Create array with words
let words = e.innerHTML.split(' ');
// Object with CSS classes and corresponding letter
const classes = {
    a: 'class-one',
    b: 'class-two',
    // and so on
}
// Return array with the new strings
words = words.map(word => {
    const firstLetter = word.substring(0,1);
    return `<span class="${classes[firstLetter]}">${word}</span>`;
});
// Join the array and update the DOM
e.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
```

Here the following is happening:

- Words are being separated by a space, creating an array;
- The `classes` constant must receive, as in the example, the correspondence of each letter with its class;
- In the function of the `map` method, the first letter of the word is being returned and the classes object is accessed with that letter;
- Finally we do a `join` to join all the texts separating them with a space.

**Remembering that if there is more than one space between words, inconsistencies will occur, as the first letter will be a space.**

Answer (score 0):

From the [string.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) reference, you can also add a *replace function* to the method, instead of an string. The replace function has [this form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

So, if I didn't misinterpret your problem, you can do something similar to this:

```
let e = document.getElementById('words');

e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/(^|<\/?[^>]+>|\s+)([^\s<]+)/g, function(match, p1, p2) {
    const myClasses = {
        a: "aword",
        b: "bword",
        ...
    }
    return `${p1}<span class="${myClasses[p2[0]]}">${p2}</span>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

1. Select all the children
2. map them with their text content
3. Split the text into single words
4. map again with some styled html
5. Join, render and enjoy.

```js
words.innerHTML = [...words.children].flatMap(el => el.innerText.replace(/\n/ig, " ").split(" ")).map(el => `<div class="someClass">${el}</div>`).join("")
```

```css
.someClass {
  color: red;
  background: orange;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="words">
  <div>
    Some dummy content
    <span>Some other nested dummy content</span>
  </div>
  <p>Some sibling content</p>
</div>
```